# ASP.NET + QueryString Encoding Problem

Tags: asp.net

I'm passing query string parameter to .aspx page with 'Ñ' character in value.
But Request.QueryString returns some other box '[]' character in return.
I think this request encoding issue. and I do not want to use that HttpUtility.UrlDecode and HttpUtility.UrlEncode methods.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: Why don't you want to use HttpUtility.UrlDecode and HttpUtility.UrlEncode ? This is exactly what they are for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to be a little more precise as how you are passing this parameter and where does it come from but you could set request and response encoding in your web.config file:

```
<system.web>
    <globalization requestEncoding="utf-8" responseEncoding="utf-8" />
</system.web>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should look [Base 64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) encoding scheme to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it's a different character? It could be that the 'Ñ' isn't representable in whatever font the IDE is using to inspect it (assuming that's where you're seeing the "box").

Comment: I'm sure that it is a different char. as it return false when i perform a string comparision

Answer (score 0):

Solved.
'N' with Tilde => 'Ñ' comes under ISO-8859-1

Use following under web.config

```
<system.web> 
    <globalization requestEncoding="iso-8859-1" responseEncoding="iso-8859-1" /> 
</system.web>
```